# Exclude shortcusts from openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net

How to exclude shortcuts to not see them in openfiledialog. 
This s my current code:

```
 Dim openPicDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
                'OpenPicDialog.FileName = "OpenFileDialog1"
                openPicDialog.Multiselect = True
                openPicDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png"
                openPicDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
                If openPicDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    For Each File In openPicDialog.FileNames
                        AddImgToList(File)
                    Next
                Else
```

By shortcut i mean icon which is referencing to "real file"

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. It's hard to understand what `shortcut` you are referring to

Comment: @The Apache if you simply make icon which is referencing to "real file"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.dereferencelinks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Hans Passant either i set true or false to it i still see shotcuts in oopened window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenFileDialog exclude shortcuts from view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559058/openfiledialog-exclude-shortcuts-from-view)